# How to make a number with commas as thousands separator in table, javascript

Tags: javascript, razor

I want to print an integer with a comma as a separator, for example 10,234,234
in the price column.
I have made the function, but I am a little confused how to make it in the table.  Below is my code

```
 <table class="table">
     <tr>
      <th> Item</th>
      <th>Price</th>
     </tr>
      @foreach (SHOP.ViewModels.ItemViewModel item in Model.Itemss)
      {
         <tr>
           <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.itemName) </td>
           <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.itemPrice)</td>
         </tr>
      }
      <tr>
          <td></td>
            <td> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TotalPrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "validationCheck();", @readonly = "readonly" } }) </td>
      </tr>
 </table>
 <script>
    function numberSeparator(x) {
        return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: You never seem to call your JavaScript function anywhere.  Can you show us how you want the number `10,234,234` to be displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get all second `td` elements in the table and then update the content using the code.

```
<table class="table" id="table">
<!-- set id to get table^^^^^^^^---->
     <tr>
      <th> Item</th>
      <th>Price</th>
     </tr>
      @foreach (SHOP.ViewModels.ItemViewModel item in Model.Itemss)
      {
         <tr>
           <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.itemName) </td>
           <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.itemPrice)</td>
         </tr>
      }
 </table>
 <script>
    function numberSeparator(x) {
        return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }
    // get all second tds
    [...document.querySelectorAll('#table tr > td:nth-child(2)')].forEach(e => {
        // get text content and update
        e.textContent =  numberSeparator(e.textContent.trim());
    })
 </script>
```

**FYI :** It's always better to do it from the backend side if possible. There may be some functions available in your backend framework/programming language.

---

**UPDATE :** In your updated code you are creating an input so get input element update it's value.

```
<table class="table">
     <tr>
      <th> Item</th>
      <th>Price</th>
     </tr>
      @foreach (SHOP.ViewModels.ItemViewModel item in Model.Itemss)
      {
         <tr>
           <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.itemName) </td>
           <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.itemPrice)</td>
         </tr>
      }
      <tr>
          <td></td>
            <td> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TotalPrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "validationCheck();", @readonly = "readonly" } }) </td>
      </tr>
 </table>
 <script>
   function numberSeparator(x) {
        return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }
    // get all second tds
    [...document.querySelectorAll('#table tr > td:nth-child(2) input')].forEach(e => {
        // get text content and update
        e.value =  numberSeparator(e.value.trim());
    })
 </script>
```

Comment: Hi dude, 

I want to ask again, I just edited my code above. where there is a textbox under the column price which is used to add up the total price. for this, I have made the function but I do not include it in the code above. when I add the code you provided, the textbox disappears. maybe because it's the same in the second tds. @Pranav C Balan

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toLocaleString` to display a number with comma separators

```
let num = 1000000
let display = num.toLocaleString('us-US')
console.log(display)   // 1,000,000
```

I suspect your code could work like this

```
@foreach (SHOP.ViewModels.ItemViewModel item in Model.Itemss)
  {
     <tr>
       <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.itemName) </td>
       <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.itemPrice.toLocaleString('us-US'))</td>
     </tr>
  }
```

Comment: there is no toLocaleString after itemPrice @Kokodoko